# How to configure nginx reverse proxy to use SECURE websockets upstream?

Tags: nginx, websocket

I want to use nginx as a reverse proxy for websocket connections.

Consider **echo.websocket.org** to be my backend websocket service. As a test client I use **wscat** from https://github.com/websockets/wscat.

What works:

**client <-- ws --> backend**:
`wscat --connect ws://echo.websocket.org`

**client <-- wss -->**: `wscat --connect wss://echo.websocket.org`

**client <-- ws --> proxy <-- ws --> backend**: `wscat --connect ws://localhost` with the following nginx configuration:

```
events {
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://echo.websocket.org;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

**client <-- wss --> proxy <-- ws --> backend**: `wscat -n --connect wss://localhost` with the following nginx configuration:

```
events {
}

http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /pki/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /pki/key.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://echo.websocket.org;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want and what I need help with is configuring nginx to use secure websockets to connect to the backend. I want this configuration:

**client <-- wss --> proxy <-- wss --> backend**

I tried changing http://echo.websocket.org to https://echo.websocket.org without success. This leads to a 504 Gateway Timeout.

Comment: I think you're missing the proxy SSL certificate settings. Look at the [`proxy_ssl_certificate` documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_certificate) and the [Securing HTTP Traffic to Upstream Servers guide](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/)... it should (probably) work with WebSockets just as well.

Comment: I have no idea what changed between friday and today, but it is working now, without changing anything. Thank you anyway for making me try again :D

Comment: I’m happy it’s working :)

Comment: @merl Please look into sample, probably certificates or domain info was not updated yesterday, mey be it can be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `proxy_ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` as specified in [Nginx Docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/)

Answer (score 0):

This is my config `upstream`, `server_name`, `ssl_certificate`, `HTTP 301`:

```
server {
    listen 80; # nginx 80
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        # Set correct content type. According to this:
        # https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/using-the-webroot-domain-verification-method/1445/29
        # Current specification requires "text/plain" or no content header at all.
        # It seems that "text/plain" is a safe option.
        default_type "text/plain";
        # This directory must be the same as in /etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini
        # as "webroot-path" parameter. Also don't forget to set "authenticator" parameter
        # there to "webroot".
        # Do NOT use alias, use root! Target directory is located here:
        # /var/www/common/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/
        root         /var/www/html;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/***0***0.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/***0***0.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name ***0***0.ru; # server name
    location /sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_pass http://node; # wep application
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://node;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /smpp {
        rewrite /smpp(.*) /$1 break;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        proxy_pass http://smpp;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
upstream smpp {
    server localhost:5001;
}
upstream node {
    server localhost:5000;
}
```